# Foreach loop on smarty not returning what I expect

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to use foreach loop on smarty to list all the lockers/carriers from an array. I suspect there might be something wrong with the array but I can't pinpoint the problem.

My code is:

```
{foreach from=$delivery_points.lockers item=carrier name=myLoop}
            <option value="{$carrier->id}" 
                    {if $carrier->id eq  $selected_deliveryID } selected {/if}
                    > {$carrier.address->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}

                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                {$carrier->street|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                {$carrier->postalCode|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
                &nbsp;
          <!--  {*    {$carrier->City|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'} *}  -->
            
            </option>
            {/foreach}
```

My array is:

```
Array ( [lockers] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => BOX2756 [address] => Array ( [street] => Puijonkatu 23 [postalCode] => 70100 [city] => Kuopio [country] => FI [coordinate] => Array ( [latitude] => 62.893268049685 [longitude] => 27.68189435171 ) ) [name] => Kauppakeskus Sektori [directions] => Budbee Box sijaitsee Kauppakeskus Sektorin liukuportaiden vieressä. [openingHours] => Array ( [periods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => MONDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => MONDAY [time] => 18:00 ) ) [1] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => TUESDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => TUESDAY [time] => 18:00 ) ) [2] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => WEDNESDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => WEDNESDAY [time] => 18:00 ) ) [3] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => THURSDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => THURSDAY [time] => 18:00 ) ) [4] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => FRIDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => FRIDAY [time] => 18:00 ) ) [5] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => SATURDAY [time] => 09:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => SATURDAY [time] => 15:00 ) ) ) [weekdayText] => Array ( [0] => maanantaina: 08 – 18 [1] => tiistaina: 08 – 18 [2] => keskiviikkona: 08 – 18 [3] => torstaina: 08 – 18 [4] => perjantaina: 08 – 18 [5] => lauantaina: 09 – 15 [6] => sunnuntaina: Closed ) ) [estimatedDelivery] => 2022-03-09T12:30:00.000Z [cutoff] => 2022-03-06T17:18:52.665Z [distance] => 3877 [label] => Kauppakeskus Sektori (9.3.2022 ~14:30) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => BOX2736 [address] => Array ( [street] => Särkiniementie 1 [postalCode] => 70700 [city] => Kuopio [country] => FI [coordinate] => Array ( [latitude] => 62.880945998267 [longitude] => 27.634710015346 ) ) [name] => Kuopio Neste K Särkiniemi [directions] => Budbee Box sijaitsee liikkeen sisällä juomahyllyjä vastapäätä. [openingHours] => Array ( [periods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => MONDAY [time] => 06:30 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => MONDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [1] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => TUESDAY [time] => 06:30 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => TUESDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [2] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => WEDNESDAY [time] => 06:30 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => WEDNESDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [3] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => THURSDAY [time] => 06:30 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => THURSDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [4] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => FRIDAY [time] => 06:30 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => FRIDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [5] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => SATURDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => SATURDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [6] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => SUNDAY [time] => 09:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => SUNDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) ) [weekdayText] => Array ( [0] => maanantaina: 06 – 21 [1] => tiistaina: 06 – 21 [2] => keskiviikkona: 06 – 21 [3] => torstaina: 06 – 21 [4] => perjantaina: 06 – 21 [5] => lauantaina: 08 – 21 [6] => sunnuntaina: 09 – 21 ) ) [estimatedDelivery] => 2022-03-09T12:00:00.000Z [cutoff] => 2022-03-06T17:18:52.673Z [distance] => 5758 [label] => Kuopio Neste K Särkiniemi (9.3.2022 ~14:00) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => BOX2755 [address] => Array ( [street] => Savilahdentie 10 [postalCode] => 70700 [city] => Kuopio [country] => FI [coordinate] => Array ( [latitude] => 62.887744149582 [longitude] => 27.634239326918 ) ) [name] => Prisma Kuopio [directions] => Löydät Budbee Boxin myymälän vasemman sisäänkäynnin läheisyydestä, leipomon jälkeiseltä automaattialueelta. Huomaa ettei myymälän muut kaikki sisäänkäynnit ole avoinna 24/7. [openingHours] => Array ( [periods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => MONDAY [time] => 00:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => MONDAY [time] => 23:30 ) ) [1] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => TUESDAY [time] => 00:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => TUESDAY [time] => 23:30 ) ) [2] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => WEDNESDAY [time] => 00:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => WEDNESDAY [time] => 23:30 ) ) [3] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => THURSDAY [time] => 00:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => THURSDAY [time] => 23:30 ) ) [4] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => FRIDAY [time] => 00:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => FRIDAY [time] => 23:30 ) ) [5] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => SATURDAY [time] => 00:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => SATURDAY [time] => 23:30 ) ) [6] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => SUNDAY [time] => 00:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => SUNDAY [time] => 23:30 ) ) ) [weekdayText] => Array ( [0] => maanantaina: 00 – 23 [1] => tiistaina: 00 – 23 [2] => keskiviikkona: 00 – 23 [3] => torstaina: 00 – 23 [4] => perjantaina: 00 – 23 [5] => lauantaina: 00 – 23 [6] => sunnuntaina: 00 – 23 ) ) [estimatedDelivery] => 2022-03-09T12:30:00.000Z [cutoff] => 2022-03-06T17:18:52.683Z [distance] => 5909 [label] => Prisma Kuopio (9.3.2022 ~14:30) ) [3] => Array ( [id] => BOX2758 [address] => Array ( [street] => Pirtinkaari 28 [postalCode] => 70820 [city] => Kuopio [country] => FI [coordinate] => Array ( [latitude] => 62.828854344746 [longitude] => 27.666087775005 ) ) [name] => K-Market Pirtti Kuopio [directions] => Budbee Box sijaitsee K-Market Pirtin kassojen vieressä. [openingHours] => Array ( [periods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => MONDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => MONDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [1] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => TUESDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => TUESDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [2] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => WEDNESDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => WEDNESDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [3] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => THURSDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => THURSDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [4] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => FRIDAY [time] => 08:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => FRIDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [5] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => SATURDAY [time] => 09:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => SATURDAY [time] => 21:00 ) ) [6] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => SUNDAY [time] => 11:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => SUNDAY [time] => 20:00 ) ) ) [weekdayText] => Array ( [0] => maanantaina: 08 – 21 [1] => tiistaina: 08 – 21 [2] => keskiviikkona: 08 – 21 [3] => torstaina: 08 – 21 [4] => perjantaina: 08 – 21 [5] => lauantaina: 09 – 21 [6] => sunnuntaina: 11 – 20 ) ) [estimatedDelivery] => 2022-03-09T13:30:00.000Z [cutoff] => 2022-03-06T17:18:52.692Z [distance] => 6631 [label] => K-Market Pirtti Kuopio (9.3.2022 ~15:30) ) [4] => Array ( [id] => BOX2698 [address] => Array ( [street] => Matkuksentie 60 [postalCode] => 70800 [city] => Kuopio [country] => FI [coordinate] => Array ( [latitude] => 62.823111188762 [longitude] => 27.604285187022 ) ) [name] => H&M Matkus Kuopio [directions] => Budbee Box sijaitsee kauppakeskus Matkuksen H&M-myymälässä. Löydät Boxin naistenosastolta, liukuportaiden vierestä myymälän pohjakerroksessa. [openingHours] => Array ( [periods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => MONDAY [time] => 10:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => MONDAY [time] => 20:00 ) ) [1] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => TUESDAY [time] => 10:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => TUESDAY [time] => 20:00 ) ) [2] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => WEDNESDAY [time] => 10:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => WEDNESDAY [time] => 20:00 ) ) [3] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => THURSDAY [time] => 10:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => THURSDAY [time] => 20:00 ) ) [4] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => FRIDAY [time] => 10:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => FRIDAY [time] => 20:00 ) ) [5] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => SATURDAY [time] => 10:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => SATURDAY [time] => 19:00 ) ) [6] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [day] => SUNDAY [time] => 11:00 ) [close] => Array ( [day] => SUNDAY [time] => 18:00 ) ) ) [weekdayText] => Array ( [0] => maanantaina: 10 – 20 [1] => tiistaina: 10 – 20 [2] => keskiviikkona: 10 – 20 [3] => torstaina: 10 – 20 [4] => perjantaina: 10 – 20 [5] => lauantaina: 10 – 19 [6] => sunnuntaina: 11 – 18 ) ) [estimatedDelivery] => 2022-03-09T13:00:00.000Z [cutoff] => 2022-03-06T17:18:52.700Z [distance] => 9316 [label] => H&M Matkus Kuopio (9.3.2022 ~15:00) ) ) )
```

Basically I know I need a nested foreach loop for street, but why does the id not return anything?

I can see that this code results in five separate option blocks but they are all empty (even the ID).

```
<option value=""> 

                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                
                &nbsp;
          <!--    -->
            
            </option>
                        <option value=""> 

                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                
                &nbsp;
          <!--    -->
            
            </option>
                        <option value=""> 

                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                
                &nbsp;
          <!--    -->
            
            </option>
                        <option value=""> 

                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                
                &nbsp;
          <!--    -->
            
            </option>
                        <option value=""> 

                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                
                &nbsp;
          <!--    -->
            
            </option>
```

What am I doing wrong with this array?

Comment: I've not used smarty in a long time, but maybe try with: `$carrier['id']` instead?

Comment: @PaulT. is right about the syntax, $carrier['id'] is the right way of accessing an array value in smarty.